# variable failed to print for text in vue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vuex

I'm using a library but I got Close {{myVar}} printed on the screen. How do I use template literal in vue? I'm coming from react jsx background.

```
<template>
  <a-alert message="Info Text" type="info" close-text="Close {{myVar}}" />
   {{myVar}} /* it works here */
</template>
```

Comment: You would have to bind a variable to it. e.g.: `:close-text="myVar"` you could concat previous text with backticks ` if I'm not mistaken. `:close-text="\`Close ${myVar}\`"`

Comment: This link may be useful: [attribute bindings](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

Answer (score 0):

In vue, you can use variate like this:

```
<template>
    <a-alert message="Info Text" type="info" :close-text="myVar" />
        {{myVar}} /* it works here */
</template>

// combine with other text
<template>
    <a-alert message="Info Text" type="info" :close-text="`Close ${myVar}`" />
        {{myVar}} /* it works here */
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're passing prop `close-text` as text. For passing values other than text you need to put : as prefix, like `:prop="value"`.

More info about this:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Solution for your problem would be:

```
<template>
  <a-alert message="Info Text" type="info" :close-text="`Close ${myVar}`" />
   {{myVar}} /* it works here */
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use only one tag in root component.

Comment: This is certainly not an answer to this question. Please read the question again and try to address the problem, if you want to answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).